# How to rewrite a function from C++ to Python that converts a number from any number system to the decimal system

Tags: python, c++

I have a problem.
I have a function in cpp that converts a number from any number system to decimal. But I need a function like this in Python. I just don't know how to rewrite it to work in Python. And I can't use the built-in functions that exist in a given language to replace a number.

This is function in cpp and I need convert it to Python

```
int from_any_to_10(string number, int system)
{
    int x;
    int p = 1;
    int result = 0;
    for (int k = number.length() - 1; k >= 0; k--)
    {
        if (number[k] <= '9' && number[k] >= '0')
        {
            x = number[k] - 48;
        }
        else 
        {
            x = number[k] - 55;
        }
        
        result = result + p * x;
        p = p * system;
    }
    return result;
}
```

My code in Python looks like this:

```
def from_any_to_10(number, system):
    x = int()
    p = 1
    result = 0

    for k in range(len(number) - 1, len(number) >= 0, -1):
        if number[k] <= '9' and number[k] >= '0':
            x = number[k] - 48
        else:
            x = number[k] - 55

        result = result + p * x
        p = p * system
    return result
```

But, When I compile code in Python I get this errors:

```
File "C:\Users\LAPTOP\Desktop\Python\_INFA\main.py", line 17, in from_any_to_10
    x = number[k] - 48
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

I don't know how to rewrite it to work in Python.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: There are all kinds of issues here. I suggest you take a Python tutorial. And Python is a _very_ different language from C++. You'll have much better luck thinking of it as something entirely new instead of trying to reproduce every single C++ thing in Python. For example, `x = int()` doesn't do what you think it does. And `range()` isn't just a funny way to write a C++ loop, it's an entirely different construct.

Comment: The _immediate_ problem is that `number[k]` is a string and `48` is an integer. You can't do `"100" - 48` any more than you can do `"hotdog" - 48`.

Comment: Unlike C++, Python has no numeric integer `char` datatype. It only has strings (which might contain a single character). You will need to adapt your Python code to deal with that. This can be accomplished by using its built-in `ord()` and `chr()` functions (which do the same thing as their C++ countertypes).

Comment: C++ and Python are *completely* different languages. Your method of converting numbers won't work in Python. You'll probably need to find a new method and completely redo your python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert a number to decimal number system. We can iterate over the number from the end and take each number then multiply the number with number system to the power of its place from the last and sum them all.

[image: converting number system]

### C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
//converts any number system to decimal number system
int from_any_to_10(string number, int system){
    //converting string to uppercase
    std::transform(number.begin(), number.end(), number.begin(), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::toupper));
    int x;
    int p=1;//stores power value
    int result=0;
    //iterating over numbers in reverse order
    for(int k=number.length()-1; k>=0; k--){
        if(number[k]<='9' && number[k] >='0')
            x=number[k]-48;
        else x=number[k]-55;
        result+=p*x;
        p*=system;
    }
    return result;
}
int main(){
    cout<<from_any_to_10("125a",16)<<endl;
    cout<<from_any_to_10("1011",2)<<endl;
    cout<<from_any_to_10("11111",2)<<endl;
    cout<<from_any_to_10("A1",16)<<endl;
    cout<<from_any_to_10("a1",16)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
$ g++ number_system.cpp && ./a.out 
4698
11
31
161
161
```

### Python3

```
#converts from any number system to decimal number system
def from_any_to_10(number,system:int):
    number=number[::-1].upper()#reversing the string and converting to uppercase
    p=1
    result=0;
    for c in number:#iterating over the numbers
        if c <='9' and c>='0':
            #ord() converts a character to an integer
            x=ord(c)-48
        else:
            x=ord(c)-55
        result+=p*x
        p*=system
    return result;

if __name__=='__main__':
    print(from_any_to_10("125a",16))
    print(from_any_to_10("1011",2))
    print(from_any_to_10("11111",2))
    print(from_any_to_10("A1",16))
    print(from_any_to_10("a1",16))
```

### OUTPUT :

```
$ python3 number_system.py 
4698
11
31
161
161
```